# Better way to connect 2 enums that look identical

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Currently I have 2 enums as below

```
enum Tab {
  Approved = "Approved",
  Pending = "Pending",
  Sold = "Sold",
}

enum ProductStatus {
  Approved = "Approved",
  Pending = "Pending",
  Sold = "Sold",
}
```

I have 3 tabs for each Tab that if I click on that tab, those products whose type matches the tab are shown.

Is there any way to make this better? I'm thinking what if I need to show Deleted products, I have to manually add to Tab and ProductStatus, which is not efficient.

Logic to show specific products is

```
const products = allProducts.filter(
  (product) => (product.status as string) === (tab as string)
);
```

Thank you. I'm pretty new to TypeScript so please let me know if something is unclear

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you literally don't just use one `enum` instead of two? What exactly is the point of having two separate enums that mirror each other in the first place? Pick one and go with that, perhaps renaming it to make it more generic/flexible.

`enum` is fairly unique in TypeScript and cannot be aliased easily, for example with `type` or intersection/union types. However, since `enum` is simultaneously a map (i.e. object) you can treat it as such, and do something like this (if you really, really wanted to):

```
enum Tab {
  Approved = "Approved",
  Pending = "Pending",
  Sold = "Sold",
}

const ProductStatus = Tab;

console.log(ProductStatus.Approved); // "Approved"
```

You could even extend the "aliased" enum type by adding new properties:

```
const ProductStatus = {...Tab, Discontinued: "Discontinued"};
```

Essentially you'd be choosing one `enum` to be the "base" class, and extending it from there.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to mutate `Tab` enum. It is only my thoughts

Comment: @captain-yossarian what do you mean by “mutate”? Here the original `Tab` enum would remain unchanged.

Comment: sorry, my bad, no mutation here